# Typo3 4.5 get image name from tt_content

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i'm stucking in my code now :/

I want to get the image names from my Database and format them.

Here my TS Code:

```
temp.slider = COA
temp.slider{

#slider
200 = TEXT
200.value = <div class="slider">

300 = COA
300.table = tt_content
300.select {
    orderBy = sorting
    where = (colPos = 3 AND CType = "image")
    languageField = sys_language_uid


    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        field = image
        split {
             token = ,
             cObjNum = 1
             1.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
             1.cObject {
                 file {
                     import = fileadmin/images/
                     import.current = 1
                 }
                 stdWrap.wrap = <img width="615" height="230" alt="" src="fileadmin/images/|" >
                 stdWrap.insertData = 1
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output I need is:

```
<img width="615" height="230" alt="" src="fileadmin/images/image1.jpg">
<img width="615" height="230" alt="" src="fileadmin/images/image2.jpg">
<img width="615" height="230" alt="" src="fileadmin/images/image3.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested, i guess that should work :)
Check where the images are located, i guess fileadmin/images/ is not correct. You can open the images in the backend, have a look what the path is.

```
300 = CONTENT
300.table = tt_content
300.select {
    orderBy = sorting
    where = (colPos = 3 AND CType = "image")
    languageField = sys_language_uid


    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        field = image
        split {
             token = ,
             cObjNum = 1
             1 {
                10 = IMAGE
                10 {
                   file {
                      import = uploads/pics/
                      import.current = 1
                      # "c" means cropping, so if it is not able to scale that image
                      # it will be cropped to fit 615x230
                      width = 615c
                      height = 230c
                   }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

For debugging purposes you can check what is the output of:

check if CONTENT get some content:

```
renderObj = TEXT
renderObj {
  field = image
}
```

check if split works:

```
renderObj = TEXT
renderObj {
  field = image
  split  {
    token = ,
    cObjNum = 1
    1 {
      10 = TEXT
      10.current = 1
      10.wrap = <span>This is the image filename: |</span><br />
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello maholtz, thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work :/ . The image has been uploaded to fileadmin/images, but with the corrected path i doesn't work ,too.

Comment: I guess it should be `300 = CONTENT` and not `COA`.

Comment: @cascaval Now i see something, but it is only 1 picture.
But i have 2 and more pictures in this contentelement.
And this doesn't crop the size to 615x230px :/


<img width="295" height="111" alt="" src="typo3temp/pics/dummy-slider-02_e9fc1c844b.jpg">

Comment: @demonking: Well, it's more of a question for maholtz. Looking at the IMG you posted... Is that the result you got? Are your images actually bigger than 615x230px?

Comment: @cascaval no, it is not bigger than 615x230. The size of the image i uploaded is 615x230

Comment: @demonking: what output do you get? Try to debug and try to understand what happens